# SSMS Login Password getting DELETED when the SSIS package is run using that login

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

I have created a SQL Login on a server (given SysAdmin permission to a single database on that server). And I am using this SQL Login in the SSIS package which will be basically truncating all the data from a table and then importing the data into that table.

The Login connects using SQL Server Authentication but whenever I run the SSIS package, the password gets deleted. and then I can login to SQL Server without password.

Can someone please let me know why this is happening and how to fix this?

(I add in the password to that login again and it again gets deleted when the SSIS package runs)

Thanks

Comment: "given SysAdmin permission" - overkill

Comment: You *can't* give `sysadmin` within a single database. The `syadmin` role is a *server role* and most be given to a `LOGIN`. This means that that `LOGIN` can do **whatever** they want to *any* database as well as the server. There is no equivilent of a `sysadmin` at database level. The closest is a `db_owner` (a database role), however, unlike a `sysadmin` they will respect any explicit `DENY` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Packages and Project have a Protection Level:

- DontSaveSensitive - Anything sensitive (username and password in connection managers) is not saved in the resulting XML and is only in memory
- EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey - (Default) Sensitive items are encrypted using the user account artifacts
- EncryptSensitiveWithWithPassword - An explicit password is used to encrypt the sensitive data
- EncryptAllWithUserKey - (Default) The entire XML is encrypted using the user account artifacts
- EncryptAllWithWithPassword - An explicit password is used to encrypt the the entire package

Thus, when you use DontSaveSensitive the credentials are not saved with the file. And that can be ok, you just need to supply the credentials every time you edit the package. On execution, that's where the SSISDB catalog shines as you can specify the credentials via Configuration and then they're persisted and automatically applied through all the deployments and redeployments as well as job execution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by changing the security in connection manager in SSIS Package -

In connection Manager Properties-

Security
Protection Level: EncryptSensitiveWithPassword

The previous ProtectionLevel was 'DontSaveSensitive'

Comment: What was the Protection Level at the package/project before you changed it?

Comment: It was 'DontSaveSensitive' before